# Move some but not all postgresql databases to a different directory

Tags: postgresql

I have around 10 postgresql databases on my machine. Some are huge, some are small. I want to move the huge ones to a new disk while keeping the small ones where they are. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it? All I've been able to find is how to move the whole `data` directory to a new location, but that would move *all* the databases and I only want to move some of them.

Comment: side note :  `SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('db_name'));` helps to find out the disk size of a db and please mention the OS that your PostgreSQL is installed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move them using tablespace. Here's how can You do it :

`CREATE TABLESPACE dbspace LOCATION '/data/dbs';`

Then,

`ALTER DATABASE dbname SET TABLESPACE dbspace;`

Comment: Don't forget to ALTER your tables and indexes, to move them to the new tablespace. ALTER DATABASE only changes the default location for new tables and indexes, it doesn't move the old ones.

Comment: @FrankHeikens On the contrary, `ALTER DATABASE dbname SET TABLESPACE dbspace` moved the existing tables and indexes when I used it in `postgresql 9.1`. ["This command physically moves any tables or indexes in the database's old default tablespace to the new tablespace."](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-alterdatabase.html)